Oscillation of an Integrable Function on a Subinterval is smaller than epsilon. Proof check.
Given an integrable function $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and a subinterval $[c,d] \subseteq [a,b]$ with $c < d$, we aim to prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an interval $[p, q] \subseteq [c, d]$ (with $p < q$) such that the oscillation of $f$ on $[p, q]$, denoted by $\omega(f, [p, q])$, is less than $\epsilon$. .
We know that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then it is also integrable on $[c,d]$. Then, by Darboux's Criterion, we have that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a partition $P = \{x_0, \ldots, x_n\}$ of $[c,d]$ such that
$$S(P) - s(P) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (M_i - m_i)(x_{i+1} - x_i) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} w_i(x_{i+1} - x_i) < \epsilon$$
Then, I choose some subinterval of the partition to be $[p,q]$, $[p,q] = [x_i,x_{i+1}]$, for some $i = 0, \ldots, n$ then we have
$$w(f,[p,q])(q-p) \leq \sum_{i=0}^{n} w_i(x_{i+1} - x_i) \leq S(P) - s(P) < \epsilon,$$
and hence
$$w(f,[p,q]) < \frac{\epsilon}{(p-q)}.$$
